# Creating a list polygon's vertices from two lists of points

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to construct a list of polygons by using two different lists of points:

```
list1={{0, 0.}, {0, 1.18961}, {0, 2.37923}, {0, 3.56884}, {0, 4.75846}, {0, 5.94807}, {0, 7.13769}}

list2 = {{2.70289, 0.512313}, {2.47741, 1.70193}, {2.25193, 2.89154}, {2.02645, 4.08116}, {1.80096, 5.27077}, {1.57548,6.46039}, {1.35, 7.65}}
```

The sequence/function that I tried to use to build the vertices of the polygons (5 points) is:

```
fpoly[a_Integer, x_List, y_List] = {x[[a]], y[[a]], y[[a + 1]], x[[a + 1]], x[[a]]}
```

That option does not work. I think if a type of evaluation control is used the fpoly might be an option, but I do not know how to implement it.

To build all the polygons from fpoly my plan was to use something like:

```
Table[fpoly[i,list1,list2],{i,1,6}]
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Use `SetDelayed`, i.e., `fpoly[a_Integer, x_List, y_List] := {x[[a]], y[[a]], y[[a + 1]], x[[a + 1]], x[[a]]}`

Comment: I cannot believe that I missed that. It is so basic! When I thought that I was starting to understand Mathematica and then I missed something some basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
polygoncoords = (Join @@@ 
   Partition[Transpose[{list1, list2}], 2, 1])[[All, {1, 2, 4, 3, 1}]];

polygons = Polygon /@ polygons;
```

Graph the third polygon (`polygons[[3]]`);

```
Graphics[{Blue, Line@list1, Red, Line@list2, 
  EdgeForm[rc = RandomColor[]], rc, Opacity[.5], polygons[[3]]}]
```

[image]

Graphs polygons `1`, `3` and `6` (`polygons[[{1, 3, 6}]]`):

```
Graphics[{Blue, Line @ list1, Red, Line @ list2,
 {EdgeForm[rc = RandomColor[]], rc, Opacity[.5], #} & /@ polygons[[{1, 3, 6}]]}]
```

[image]

Graph all 6 polygons:

```
Graphics[{Blue, Line @ list1, Red, Line @ list2,
  {EdgeForm[rc = RandomColor[]], rc, Opacity[.5], #} & /@ polygons}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is my favourite answer as it is very functional programming oriented

Answer (score 5):

We can select two points from the two list alternatively and use `ConvexHullMesh` to construct the convex polygon.

BTW,Here we have `Reverse` the order of the second list`list2`to keep the orientation of polygon,so we can also replace `ConvexHullMesh` by `Polygon`to make the same convex polygons.

```
list1 = {{0, 0.}, {0, 1.18961}, {0, 2.37923}, {0, 3.56884}, {0, 
    4.75846}, {0, 5.94807}, {0, 7.13769}};

list2 = {{2.70289, 0.512313}, {2.47741, 1.70193}, {2.25193, 
    2.89154}, {2.02645, 4.08116}, {1.80096, 5.27077}, {1.57548, 
    6.46039}, {1.35, 7.65}};
polygons = 
  ConvexHullMesh /@ 
   Join @@@ Tuples[{Subsets[list1, {2}], Subsets[Reverse@list2, {2}]}];
i = RandomInteger[{1, Binomial[7, 2]^2}]
Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Green], FaceForm[Directive[Opacity[.5], Yellow]], 
   polygons[[i]]}, {Red, Point[list1], Arrowheads[.1], 
   Arrow[list1]}, {Blue, Point[list2], Arrowheads[.1], Arrow[list2]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I found this solution interesting because it shows a way of using ConvexHullMesh. I really like the utilization of Graphics to show the results